# Prevent React from re-rendering a specific child component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a react component that conditionally renders several child components.  Simplified code is just:

```
render(): {
  const component1 = condition ? renderComponent2() : null;
  const component2 = renderComponent2();

  return (
    <div>
      {component1}
      {component2}
    </div>
  );
}
```

The problem is that `component2` is getting destroyed and re-rendered whenever the `condition` changes.  I'm trying to prevent that and keep the original element around.  I tried adding a `key` to `component2` with no luck.

[edit] This is happening even when `component1` always exists and I change flag on it to hide it or not with CSS :/

Comment: This should not be the case. Please show complete code reproducing this.

Comment: I can't, it's a really integrated piece of code.  Wondering if anyone has any advice on why it _can_ happen?

Comment: Why are you trying to keep the rendered component around? You can keep all the props around so it's the same when re-rendered.

Comment: My suggestion would be to keep child components as part of state. It may not be the most elegant, but it will work.

Comment: @EzraChang I don’t think this is correct. There should be no problem in the first place, and you definitely shouldn’t be putting components into the state.

Comment: @zyklus How do you tell the component is “getting destroyed and re-renderered”?

Comment: The only reason it CAN happen is if you do strange things inside the `renderComponent2()` function, which causes react to think it is a new (instead of updated) component. To get more specific answers here, you will need to share further info and/or code on what that method returns.

Comment: @Nobody why was that useless? it highlighted the new information while keeping true to the original writing.

Comment: @NoamYizraeli - You literally just changed the formatting of the word "edit" to what *you* prefer.  It adds literally nothing.

Comment: @Nobody in your opinion with all due respect, when I brief over a question, that highlighting pops out and breaks the question into its different chunks with clear points to changes (like updates or edits as in this case) which makes it more presentable and welcoming to future readers

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried doing it with [shouldComponentUpdate](http://buildwithreact.com/article/optimizing-with-shouldcomponentupdate)? This is exactly what this function should be used for. Just add it to your `component2` and add proper condition inside.

Answer (score 2):

Form the example code, your `component2` will not be destroyed and re-mounted again. 
React will run any `render` and possibly other lifecycle methods, but 
React will **Update** the component in the DOM in place.

Maybe your code is more complicated. Which causes react to think that you are not re-rendering `component2`, but instead, are trying to render a whole new component. But again, from your example code this is not clear.

You can find [proof of concept codepen here](https://codepen.io/wintvelt/pen/rLNNEL?editors=0010), which does the following:

- It renders 2 instances of `component2`, with a green background.
- Button can (*illegally*) change background color of the first component to red, outside of react's knowledge.
- By clicking the button, react will re-render the 2 components.
- The background-color remains red, which is proof that react only updates component, and does not destroy.

React will NOT reset the background color to green, because react thinks (from its virtual DOM) that the background color is unchanged and still green.

UPDATE: The codepen now also contains further proof of how it CAN happen:

- if you change the type of HTML returned (from `<p>` element to `<h1>` element in proof of concept)
- react will NOT recognize it as the same element, and destroy original and insert a new element.

PS: because your example code creates the component through a method call, any lifecycle methods (such as `shouldComponentUpdate`) should NOT be applied. Rendering components through methods should only be done for simple components, i.e. react elements. See [official docs here](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/glossary.html#react-elements):

> A ReactElement is a light, ***stateless***, immutable, virtual
>   representation of a DOM Element.

Answer (score 0):

If there is a state change in `condition` the component will re-render itself which means that `component2` will be changed too.